# bash process to copy subtitles in their respective mp4 with FFMPEG

Tags: bash, video, ffmpeg, subtitles

I have ***many*** video files (mp4), with their respective subtitles (each video and subtitle have the same name).

The idea create a bash to copy each subtitle in their video without re encode again. To the first video, I tried this command on Terminal and works like a charm:

`$ ffmpeg -i 01-01-Introduction.mp4 -fix_sub_duration -i 01-01-Introduction.srt -c:s mov_text -c:v copy -c:a copy -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1 -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng 01-01-Introduction-sub.mp4`

Some files:

1. 01-01-Introduction.mp4
2. 01-01-Introduction.srt
3. 01-02-CourseOverview.mp4
4. 01-02-CourseOverview.srt
5. and so on

any suggestions? thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

This works. To avoid overwrite the input files I modified the out variable: `"${i%.mp4}-sub.mp4"`

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
# GNU bash version 4.3.42
# To avoid overwrite files: "${i%.mp4}-sub.mp4"


for i in *.mp4; do
    SUB=${i%.mp4}.srt
    ffmpeg -i "$i" -fix_sub_duration -i "$SUB" -c:s mov_text -c:v copy -c:a copy -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1 -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng "${i%.mp4}-sub.mp4";
done
```

Thanks to @MariusMatutiae

Answer (score 2):

You should try;

```
for i in *.mp4; do
    SUB={i%%.mp4}.srt
    ffmpeg -i "$i" -fix_sub_duration -i "$SUB" -c:s mov_text -c:v copy -c:a copy -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1 -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng "$i"
 done
```

You should test the command above by copying **one** mp4 file and its subtitle in an otherwise empty directory, and try it there. If it works, then you can carry on.

Comment: Hi @MariusMatutiae I get an error: `{i%%.mp4}.srt: No such file or directory`; but thanks to your help I found out how to do it

Comment: To get just a name without a extension : `SUB=${i%.mp4}.srt`